# The relation between commutator series and the center

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a group and $R$ be a maximal solvable subgroup in $G$. Consider the commutator series $R^{(n)}=[R^{(n-1)},R^{(n-1)}]$. Assume that $R^{(k)}$ intersects the center $Z$ of $G$ in a non-trivial subgroup. Now since the last non-trivial term of the series is abelain, does that mean it equals the center $Z$?

Comment: Perhaps I have misunderstood the question, but I believe the answer is "no", as your suggestion that some $R^{(k)}$ intersects the centre of $G$ seems to be incorrect.  For instance, take $G$ to be solvable with trivial centre (e.g., a dihedral group of order $10$). Then $R=G$, and no term of the derived series meets the trivial centre in a non-trivial subgroup.

Comment: @James I would guess that rather than  "We know that" he actually means "Assume that". I am also wondering whether we are supposed to assume that $G$ itself if not solvable. But the answer to the question is no however you interpret it. The last nontrivial term in the series could be a proper subgroup of $Z$.

Comment: Sorry I actually meant that what Derek said. Assume that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we take $G = R = C_2 \times S_3$, then $R^{(0)}$ intersects $Z(G)$ non-trivially, but $R^{(1)} = (0, (123))$ which is abelian but not central.

Comment: (tbh, I'm a bit worried I've misunderstood the question, since I can't see any reason to believe the question to be true if I have not misunderstood it)